# Alarm manager works only the first time then is triggered immediately

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I am trying to create an alarm method in android , it receives a specific date/time and has to to do something at that specific time.

now the first time it works fine,then it triggers immediately even thought the specified time is in the future .

here is my code :

```
public void CreateAlarmUTC(ScheduleRequest mrequest)
{
    AlarmManager alarmMgr;
    PendingIntent alarmIntent;
    Context context;

    int index = mrequest.Index;
    context = getApplicationContext();


    ScheduledDate date = SchMs.get(mrequest.Index).ScheduledDate;
    String dat = date.calendar.getTime().toGMTString();

    int uniqueTime = date.Minutes+date.Day*10+date.Year*100+date.Hour*1000+date.Month*10000;

    alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(ALARM_SERVICE);
    intent.putExtra("index", index);

    alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, uniqueTime, intent, 0);


    alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, date.calendar.getTimeInMillis(), alarmIntent); 
}
```

ScheduleRequest is a class that I created , and it has an index refers to the place of an object in an array called SchMs.

ScheduledDate is a class that I created , it has a Calendar object called calendar.

Here is how I create the calendar in ScheduledDate :

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, time_timePicker.getCurrentMinute());
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, time_timePicker.getCurrentHour());
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, time_datePicker.getDayOfMonth());
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, time_datePicker.getMonth());
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, time_datePicker.getYear());
```

time_timePicker is a TimePicker in my activity.

time_datePicker is a DatePicker in my activity.

Any ideas?
Do you have a better way of executing a specific task at a specific time only once?

thanks

Comment: One doubt here, in your ScheduledDate class, are you doing a `Calendar.set(val,Calendar.HOUR)` or something similar? Give some information about those classes as well please.

Answer (score 0):

Finally after debugging , I found out that eclipse for some reason was adding a day more than I want only in the first time. For instance if I choose 14/09/2014 (DD/MM/YYYY) is assumes that I want 15/09/2014 , so I had to make my
ScheduledDate.calendar as Today-1 :

```
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, time_datePicker.getDayOfMonth()-1);
```

After restaring eclipse, and more debugging , I found out that it went back to normal and I should keep it as it was originaly :

```
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, time_datePicker.getDayOfMonth());
```

so now it works just fine.

** The example above ,now, works just fine.